# Angular 4: mismatch input fields with error message

Tags: javascript, angular, forms

I want to compare password field and confirm password without creating a new directive, just using ngModel and HTML. I have a submit button blocked if the passwords don't match, and thats working fine. But I want to show a span error message when the user is retyping (or on submit) and so far, right after the first input on the password field (when the retype is empty) I get the error message. It's logical, with the code I have, but I wonder if it's possible to have a better UX without using validators or directives? I've tried several aproaches but nothing worked...Any hint would be appreciated. The code:

```
<form #confirm="ngForm" novalidate>
          <mat-form-field class="full-width">
            <input matInput type="password" id="password" placeholder="New Password" name="password"
                   [(ngModel)]="loginValues.password" required>

          </mat-form-field>

          <mat-form-field class="full-width">
            <input matInput type="password" id="confirmPassword" placeholder="Retype Password" name="confirmPassword"
                   [(ngModel)]="loginValues.confirmPassword" required>

          </mat-form-field>
                <!--Error Message-->
            <span *ngIf="loginValues.confirmPassword  !== loginValues.password">{{ 'login.password_not_match' | translate }}</span>

          <div class="child-padding-top no-side-padding" fxLayoutAlign="end center" >
            <button class="button-login-register" [disabled]="loginValues.password !== loginValues.confirmPassword" mat-button color="primary"
                    (click)="clientNewPassword()" >{{ 'login.SUBMIT' | translate }}</button>
          </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use a span for *ngIf, unless you are using the span for a purpose (add a class to it, etc.). But it seems you are just using that to hold your *ngIf statement, since *ngIf has to be tagged to an element. If you're going to do this, you should instead use

```
<ng-container *ngIf=""></ng-container>.
```

To answer your question, the only thing that I think you can do without applying validation, is to add more logic. For example you could do:

```
 <ng-container* ngIf="loginValues.confirmPassword !== loginValues.password 
    && loginValues.confirmPassword.length > 0 
    && loginValues.password.length > 0 ">
    {{ 'login.password_not_match' | translate }}
 </ng-container>
```

Basically what you're doing is changing it so that the error is not always shown when the passwords don't match, but instead the user has to have filled out both inputs first. There's other things you could do. For example you could use ngTouched/ngDirty, etc. You can set up the rules as you like them.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but with this logic I get pilled messages, I guess that I need to apply validation...

Comment: No you don't. Observe: https://plnkr.co/edit/icYnaN2WBgwDbCb5ZW2l?p=preview

Comment: my bad, thanks a lot @David Anthony Acosta, it works like a charm :)